# Read/Access Password-Protected File/PDF

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, appexchange

I want to read/access any file or pdf file when we uploaded file in lightning component. I have tried many option but there are no any possibility to get it.

If any one has know about any appexchange app or any other solution which I will implement easily in Lightning component.

Please give me any solution.

Appreciate!! If any one has give solution for this.

Answer (score -1):

You can write a trigger on ContentDocumentLink and set the visibility and share type of the file uploaded by doing:

```
for(ContentDocumentLink l:conDocList) {

     l.Visibility='AllUsers';
     l.shareType='C'                 
  }
```

So whenever a file is uploaded in the system it will be visible to all users and  the user can explicitly view and edit the shared file. Let me know oif this helps.

Comment: No, It is not working because I got "An exception occurred. Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY, Invalid sharing type C: [ShareType]" this error when I upload any file.

Comment: Changing the visibility on the ContentDocument has nothing to do with password protection on PDFs.

Comment: @David Reed, Ok, So any other solution for this.